# cannot read property of undefined, but can log it to console

Tags: node.js, express, post, telegram-bot

I am trying to retrieve data from a post request in Express, and pass that data on to a function that then responds with a post request once it has enriched that data.

For some reason, the request fails to go through, supposedly due to a TypeError: "Cannot read property 'text' of undefined"

Strange thing is, I can access the same property on the incoming request, and log it to console, one line above where the property supposedly cannot be read.

I've rewritten the code a little bit, it used to have quite a few promises and async / await in it. I think this might have lead to this issue, but I cannot figure out why there is still a conflict.

//app.js

```
app.use("/", routes);
```

//routes.js

```
routes.post("/", controller.postRequest);
```

//controller.js

```
app.use("/", middleware.jsonParse);

const postRequest = app.post("/", (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("request is in postRequest function");
    console.log(req.body.message.text);
    let msg = req.body.message.text;
    let chat_id = req.body.message.chat.id;
    if (msg.indexOf("/weather") > -1) {
        try {
            const forecast = getForecast.forecast;

            if (forecast) {
                console.log("found forecast");
                try {
                    sendMessage.sendMessage(forecast, chat_id);
                } catch (error) {
                    throw error;
                }
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            throw error;
        }
    } else {
        try {
            sendMessage.sendMessage("I did not understand you", chat_id);
        } catch (error) {
            throw error;
        }
    }
    res.status(200).end();
});
```

//getForecast.js

```
const forecast = async () => {
    console.log("request is in forecast");
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(full_url);
        return response;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};
```

//sendMessage.js

```
const sendMessage = (forecast, chat_id) => {
    axios
        .post(config.telegram_base_url + "/sendMessage", {
            chat_id: chat_id,
            text: forecast
        })
        .then(response => {
            return response;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
};
```

This is the error message I am getting. For some reason it seems to also be running through the code twice everytime before I get one of the errors?

```
Server now listening on port 3000
request received
request got to router
request got to controller
request is in postRequest function
/weather
request received
request got to router
request got to controller
request is in postRequest function
(node:27408) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined
    at app.post (/Users/louissugar/Documents/projects/weather_bot/controller.js:17:31)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/louissugar/Documents/projects/weather_bot/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/louissugar/Documents/projects/weather_bot/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/louissugar/Documents/projects/weather_bot/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/louissugar/Documents/projects/weather_bot/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /Users/louissugar/Documents/projects/weather_bot/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/Users/louissugar/Documents/projects/weather_bot/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/louissugar/Documents/projects/weather_bot/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at next (/Users/louissugar/Documents/projects/weather_bot/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:127:14)
    at app.post (/Users/louissugar/Documents/projects/weather_bot/controller.js:12:2)
(node:27408) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
```

Comment: does the `req.body.message.text = '/weather'`? if so your api is being called twice, once with body and once without. check your front end if it is sending two calls. in the dev tools of the browser

Comment: @Jazib yes, the text is '/weather'. I don't have a frontend though, since this is part of a telegram bot

Answer (score 0):

you are sending "chat_id" in the body, but trying to read chat.id so you should send `chat:{id:xxx}`

Comment: I'm storing the chat.id from the request in the variable chat_id in line 7 in controller.js

('let chat_id = req.body.message.chat.id;')

and passing it into the sendMessage method later in the block

Answer (score 0):

Why am I not seeing the console log out "request is in forecast" from //getForecast.js

What is the value of 'const forecast' after getForecast.forecast is run?